# Insert integer to Arabic String in Start

Tags: c#, string, arabic

I am trying to add integer to Arabic string but no success

```
// Arabic String  
Astr = "سُوْرَةُ الْفَاتِحَة";
// String with Integer   -1
num = "-"+1;
// Adding Strings
r = Astr + num;  
r = num + Astr;
```

output : `سُوْرَةُ الْفَاتِحَة-1`

Desired output:

```
سُوْرَةُ الْفَاتِحَة‎-1
```

I want the integer on the right side .

Update : Am displaying this result in `ListBox` in visual studio by using `Items.Insert()` Method , so if anyone know to tweak ListBox then kindly share I mean if `ListBox` display Numbers 1  2  3  4 with each row ?

Comment: Did you try using the integer `-1` instead of adding a dash and an integer `1`?

Comment: @HABO ya it tried with 1 too without dash ...... but same result

Comment: @Alex  thanks for suggestion but "-1" not worked same result :(

Comment: This is not a bad question, I can't really seem to even type it in comment `سُوْرَةُ الْفَاتِحَة`  with - 1

Comment: @Habib ya i tried too :D we need someone expert to answer that question

Comment: Can you use a seperate control to display the number sign? You can try to blend the two part together by using no boundary line but the same background color.

Comment: I beleive it has to do with culture info, right to left vs left to right.

Comment: @TianyunLing  do you have link to any example related to this technique , but using no boundary line

Comment: It is a walk around (or cheat) rather than a technique. You can change the style of the control in the design panel (maybe make them transparent). And have a bigger background panel contains the two controls to make them looks as one.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use Unicode [LRM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left-to-right_mark) (200F)

```
string Astr = "سُوْرَةُ الْفَاتِحَة";
var num = "-1";
var LRM = ((char)0x200E).ToString(); 
var result = Astr + LRM + num;
```

and you will get: `result = "سُوْرَةُ الْفَاتِحَة‎-1"`

See: [HOW TO: Formatting Control Characters](http://www.microsoft.com/middleeast/msdn/Control.aspx#RLM)

> LRM ==>   Left-to-Right Mark ==>  200E    ==> Acts as a Latin character.

Comment: @habib i knew the basic is right to left formating , thanks !

Comment: if i used it on url it add hidden string 200E what shall i do